# write html file that contains a link that open excel application in a specific sheet & row

Tags: html, excel, href

I'm writing a very simple HTML file that contains some tables.
I'm trying to have a cell value, which is basically a link. by clicking on the link I'd like to open a file in an excel application in a specific sheet and row.

Notes:

1. windows environment
2. HTML is opened by a standard browser
3. the file exists locally (simple path: C:\test.xlsx)
4. excel application path is unknown
5. I'd like to keep the HTML file as simple as possible. good design is not a top priority. just need to make it happen.
6. (low priority) if excel instance (for a specific file) is already open, I'd like to change the active sheet and highlight the row in the open instance

Comment: Where is the HTML file being loaded from? You can use javascript (or vbscript) in IE to automate Excel, so that would be an option if the HTML is being loaded from the local filesystem or a "trusted" location.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_excel_file(path,sheet,f_range)
      {

        if (!window.ActiveXObject)
        {
          alert ("Your browser does not support this feature.\n"
                 "Please re-open this file using IE browser.");
          return;
        }

        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (!fso.FileExists(path))
          alert("Cannot open file.\nFile '" + path + "' doesn't exist.");

        else
         {
           var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

           if (myApp != null)
             {
               myApp.visible = true;
               Book = myApp.workbooks.open(path);
               var excel_sheet = Book.Worksheets(sheet).Activate;
               myApp.range(f_range).Select;
             }

           else {
             alert ("Cannot open Excel application");
           }
         }
      }
 </script>
```

usage example:

```
<button onclick="open_excel_file('f1.csv', 's1', 'A1:Z7');">Open</button>
```

Comment: Where you have defined the path ?

Comment: `<input type="button" id="dl"  onclick="open_excel_file('/inventory-web/Files/Example.xlsx','Sheet1','A1:Z7')" name="Download" class="btn btn-info" ></input>` I have done this but still it's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<Title>Excel Linking Example</Title>
</HEAD>
<body>
<p>
<a href="http://localhost/excel/asheet.xls#Sheet2!D4">
This link will open the Excel file to the second page with the focus on
cell D4</a>.
<a href="http://localhost/excel/asheet.xls#TableName">
This link will set the focus on a named area of the spreadsheet
</a>.
</p>
<form>
<input type=button
 value="Via Jscript"
 onclick='location.href = "asheet.xls#TableName"'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197922

Comment: OP's Excel files are on the local filesystem. This approach will only work for files accessed via HTTP.