# Is it possible to disable or hide file "save" option in file download dialog through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, browser, download

In file download dialog, I just want to give option to view the file. So is there any possibility to disable or hide the "SAVE" option through jquery. Currently I am loading the file download dialog to "iframe".

[image: file-download-dialog]

Comment: This is build in browser. You cant disable it.

Comment: Even if you could, the user could still save from Excel (in this case).

Comment: thank you guys for the point. yes, the user can still be able to save it. The main concern is to not induce them to save it, as saving concerned with storage. actually the file formats are ppt,doc,pdf and xls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog is provided by your browser, so you cannot alter it from your codebase.

If you have a file which can be viewed inside a browser (like txt or pdf), you could advice the browser in a link to open it instead of downloading it.

Via javascript you can try to open the file directly omitting the dialog alltogether.
[See this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487483/write-html-file-that-contains-a-link-that-open-excel-application-in-a-specific-s)

Comment: Thanks for the link. This give me different perspective. Instead of going with file download dialog. Decided to load file content in iframe as the file types vary.