# Java - How can I open file(.xlsx, .doc) automatically before download in windows using java/javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, file, window

When a user clicks on download link file should be open automatically(or just a dialogue box with only Open option but not with save/saveas).

Below is working only for PDF file formats but not with doc, xlsx files

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
```

Even I tried below to hide save button but it didn't work(means did not hide save option)

```
response.setHeader("X-Download-Options", "nosave");
```

Environment:
Windows8
Mozilla/IE - Tried in both

**Note:** *This should be done from the server end. We don't have many options to suggest user change options in user's machine.*

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897651/is-it-possible-to-disable-or-hide-file-save-option-in-file-download-dialog-thr) but did not help much

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `When a user clicks on download link file should be open automatically(or just a dialogue box with only Open option but not with save/saveas).` That is not possible. Also, note that even if the file is opened in the browser - as your PDF example is - the file can still be saved to the client machine very easily (although it technically already is in the Temp folder, but thats semantics)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Thanks for your reply. I don't bother if it's saved in default/temp folder. But I am just looking for possibility & way of implementation at this moment.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's not possible. You cannot prevent a user from saving content served to them on the web to their local machine - that's just how the web works. If you don't want something to be public, don't put it online